# "command not found: tshark" error on command line when wireshark app is already downloaded and running

Tags: macos, wireshark

I would like to use tshark from the command line. I have been using the Wireshark application on Mac OSX (10.15.3), but `tshark` in Terminal gave me the error:

`command not found: tshark`

I tried moving the tshark and tshark.dSYM files  from the Package Contents of the application (`Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/`) to `/usr/local/bin` because of a comment I found online. Now I'm getting the error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libwireshark.13.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/tshark
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      tshark
```

Seems like progress, but I'm not sure what other files need to be moved to where to be able to run tshark commands from Terminal?

Comment: What's the result of `which tshark` and `which wireshark`?

Answer (score 12):

You can solve the problem by using symbolic links.
Create a symbolic link for tshark in /usr/local/bin as such.

```
ln -s /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/tshark /usr/local/bin/tshark
```

Now if you run `tshark -v` you should see the current version of tshark installed